# unit tests which need CDI container result in java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI

Tags: unit-testing, cdi, junit5, weld

I'm using Weld for CDI.

I'm trying to write a unit test for service "A" using JUnit 5.
The constructor of service A is:

```
@Inject
public A (B b) {this.b = b}
```

Class B constructor is:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class B{ 

private C c;
    public B() {
        c = CDI.current().select(C.class).get();
    }
}
```

When i try to mock Class B during unit tests i get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access CDI

because during unit tests there isn't a proper CDI container.

How can resolve this issue? is there anyway to it with Mockito? (let's assume that replacing the CDI.current() is not an option)

This how the test code looks:

```
public class ATest {
private A a;

@WeldSetup
    private WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(A.class)
        .addBeans(createBBean()).build();

    private Bean<?> createBBean() {
        return MockBean.builder()
            .types(B.class)
            .scope(ApplicationScoped.class)
            .creating(new B())
            .build();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpClass() {
        a = weld.select(A.class).get();
     }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I see how "there isn't a proper CDI container."? You are using weld-junit in your tests which means that, if setup properly, you have a CDI SE container running. In fact just using weld-junit means you shouldn't need that mocked bean (unless you want some different behavior) as CDI would be able to construct it on its own. Can you elaborate on what wasn't working without that mocked bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always do this (CDI 2.0 and later):

```
private SeContainer container;

@BeforeEach
private void startContainer() {
  SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
  // add what you want, disable discovery, whatever
  this.container = initializer.initialize();
}

@AfterEach
private void stopContainer() {
  if (this.container != null) {
    this.container.close();
  }
}
```

Then any `@Test` has access to CDI.

Comment: I got "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No valid CDI implementation found" exception.